# How to get text from unknown nth childern p tag using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to get the description of the event. but the problem is that the description of all the events is at arbitrary `<p>` tag. so How can we access that `<p>` tag to get its text?

```css
<div id='main'>
   <div class='templatecontent'>
       <h3>Evening Tide Talk-POSTPONED<img alt="" src="https://assets.speakcdn.com/assets/2204/hj_scope-2020022008493216.jpg" style="margin: 4px 14px; float: right; width: 300px; height: 463px;" /></h3>

       <p><strong>March 25th | 5:45 p.m. </strong></p>

       <p><strong>Dr. Heather Judkins</strong></p>

       <p><strong>University of South Florida St. Petersburg, Department of Biological Sciences</strong></p>

       <p><strong><em>Lessons Learned from Exploring the Deep</em></strong></p>
       <!-- I want to get this Paragraph --!>

       <p>In her talk, Heather will share lessons learned and some unexpected finds from her journeys. Join us as she discusses unique cephalopod adaptations and memorable moments, while also sharing some “giant” findings from her most recent Gulf of Mexico cruise that led to breaking news in June 2019’s New York Times!</p>

       <p><a class="button-primary" href="/eveningtidetalks">Learn More</a></p>

       <p> </p>

       <p> </p>

       <p> </p>

       <hr />
       <h3>Washed Ashore - Art To Save The Sea <img alt="" src="https://assets.speakcdn.com/assets/2204/tfa_washed_ashore_exhibit_priscilla2.png" style="margin: 3px 13px; float: right; width: 300px; height: 300px;" /></h3>

       <p><strong><strong>February 29th - August 31st</strong></strong></p>

       <!-- I want to get this Paragraph --!>
       <p>In honor of the Aquarium's 25th Anniversary celebration, we are proud to host Washed Ashore - Art To Save The Sea from now until the end of August! The nationally acclaimed exhibit artistically showcases the impacts of plastic pollution on oceans, waterways and wildlife. Washed Ashore sculptures have traveled around the country and The Florida Aquarium is showcasing 18 larger than life sculptures of marine life. </p>

       <p><a class="button" href="/washed-ashore">Learn More</a></p>

       <p> </p>

       <hr />
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a combination of the [`following-sibilng` axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#axes) to choose the `<p>` tags at the same level as the `h3`, and then restrict those matching `p` to ones which have `text()` as an immediate child. However, if one just does `p[text()]`, it will bring back the (more or less) empty `<p> </p>` which is suboptimal. Therefore, toss in a further restriction with [`string-length`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-length) to have it only return ones that seem "interesting", yielding:

```python
def parse(self, response):
    main_div = response.css('#main')
    for h3 in main_div.xpath('.//h3'):
        talk_title = h3.xpath('text()').get()
        talk_summary = h3.xpath('./following-sibling::p[string-length(text()) > 2]/text()').get()
```

produces:

```javascript
[
  {
    "talk_title": "Evening Tide Talk-POSTPONED",
    "talk_summary": "In her talk, Heather will share lessons learned and some unexpected finds from her journeys. Join us as she discusses unique cephalopod adaptations and memorable moments, while also sharing some “giant” findings from her most recent Gulf of Mexico cruise that led to breaking news in June 2019’s New York Times!"
  },
  {
    "talk_title": "Washed Ashore - Art To Save The Sea ",
    "talk_summary": "In honor of the Aquarium's 25th Anniversary celebration, we are proud to host Washed Ashore - Art To Save The Sea from now until the end of August! The nationally acclaimed exhibit artistically showcases the impacts of plastic pollution on oceans, waterways and wildlife. Washed Ashore sculptures have traveled around the country and The Florida Aquarium is showcasing 18 larger than life sculptures of marine life. "
  }
]
```

The `following-sibling::p` axis says to match all `<p>` elements that are at the same level in the DOM as the element from which the XPath was anchored (the `<h3>` in our case), which produces a list of 9 `<p>` tags. The `p[]` XPath syntax says to further restrict the matching `p` tags that satisfy some predicate, of which `string-length(text()) > 2` says the string length of the immediate text child node must be greater than 2. Then, of those matching `<p>` tags, return the first `text` child node

Comment: can you explain how this line is working? `talk_summary = h3.xpath('./following-sibling::p[string-length(text()) > 2]/text()').get()`.